CORS Error When Accessing Swagger API Deployed on AWS EC2
I have deployed a NestJS backend on an AWS EC2 instance. The Swagger UI is accessible, but when I try to hit the API using Swagger, I receive the following error:
ISSUE: Failed to fetch. Possible Reasons:

CORS
Network Failure
URL Scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Details:

The API works correctly when tested directly on the EC2 instance (e.g., using curl).
The Swagger UI is accessed via the public IP address of the EC2 instance.
The error occurs when trying to access the API endpoint through the Swagger UI.
My backend is running on http://localhost:3033, and the Swagger UI is being accessed via the public IP of the EC2 instance.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Confirmed that the backend API is accessible directly from the EC2 instance.
Verified that the server is configured to handle CORS requests by setting the appropriate CORS headers in the NestJS application.
Checked the network configurations and security groups in AWS EC2 to ensure proper access.

Environment:
NestJS version:
AWS EC2 Instance: Amazon linus(t2.micor).
Swagger version: 6.0.5
Browser: Chrome, Edge
Node.js version: Latest
CORE: 9.0.0
Request URL: http://localhost:3033/api/v1/auth/signin
Error Image Please check

have you allowed this in your cors settings of your nestjs BE
  app.enableCors({
    origin: ['http://your-ec2-public-ip', 'http://localhost:3033'], // replace with your EC2 public IP or domain
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    credentials: true,
  });


Yes, Thanks for helping, But this error is already solved.
actually, I have not defined Swagger server URL.
